# How to solve SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, unix

I am working on a program to read data from a text file and encode it with a Huffman encoding.  I've run it 2-3 times, and it shows nothing but an error message:

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> __strcpy_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S:57
> 57    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S: No such file or directory.
> ```

When I debugged the program,  I traced the problem to the following function:

```
// walk the tree and put 0s and 1s
void build_bcode_from_tree(node n, char *s, int len)
{
    static char *out = buf;
    if (n->c) {
        s[len] = 0;
        strcpy(out, s);
        code[n->c] = out;
        out += len + 1;
        return;
    }

    s[len] = '0'; build_bcode_from_tree(n->left,  s, len + 1);
    s[len] = '1'; build_bcode_from_tree(n->right, s, len + 1);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t {
    struct node_t *left, *right;
    int freq;
    char c;
} *node;

struct node_t pool[256] = {{0}};
node qqq[255], *q = qqq - 1;
int n_nodes = 0, qend = 1;
char *code[128] = {0}, buf[1024];

//creating tree
node create_tree(int freq, char c, node a, node b)
{
    node n = pool + n_nodes++;
    if (freq) n->c = c, n->freq = freq;
    else {
        n->left = a, n->right = b;
        n->freq = a->freq + b->freq;
    }
    return n;
}

// priority queue according to frequency
void qinsert(node n)
{
    int j, i = qend++;
    while ((j = i / 2)) {
        if (q[j]->freq <= n->freq) break;
        q[i] = q[j], i = j;
    }
    q[i] = n;
}

node qremove()
{
    int i, l;
    node n = q[i = 1];

    if (qend < 2) return 0;
    qend--;
    while ((l = i * 2) < qend) {
        if (l + 1 < qend && q[l + 1]->freq < q[l]->freq) l++;
        q[i] = q[l], i = l;
    }
    q[i] = q[qend];
    return n;
}

// walk the tree and put 0s and 1s
void build_bcode_from_tree(node n, char *s, int len)
{
    static char *out = buf;
    if (n->c) {
        s[len] = 0;
        strcpy(out, s);
        code[n->c] = out;
        out += len + 1;
        return;
    }

    s[len] = '0'; build_bcode_from_tree(n->left,  s, len + 1);
    s[len] = '1'; build_bcode_from_tree(n->right, s, len + 1);
}

// individual binary representation
void ind_repre(const char *s)
{
    int i, freq[128] = {0};
    char c[16];

    while (*s) freq[(int)*s++]++;

    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        if (freq[i]) qinsert(create_tree(freq[i], i, 0, 0));

    while (qend > 2)
        qinsert(create_tree(0, 0, qremove(), qremove()));

    build_bcode_from_tree(q[1], c, 0);
}

// endode the whole file data
void compress(const char *s, char *out)
{
    while (*s) {
        strcpy(out, code[*s]);
        out += strlen(code[*s++]);
    }
}

//showing decode data
void decompress(const char *s, node t)
{
    FILE *filew;
    filew = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    node n = t;
    while (*s) {
        if (*s++ == '0') n = n->left;
        else n = n->right;
        // if (n->c) putchar(n->c), n = t;
        if (n->c) fprintf(filew,"%c", n->c), n = t;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    if (t != n) printf("wrong input\n");
  fclose(filew);

}

// main function
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    const char *str;
  char buff[1024];
    // read from file
    char txt[1024];
    FILE *file;
    size_t nread;

    file = fopen("index.html", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
            printf("There is no file with this name!!\n");
            exit(-1);
    } else {

            while ((nread = fread(txt, 1, sizeof txt, file)) > 0)
                    fwrite(txt, 1, nread, stdout);
            if (ferror(file)) {

            }
            fclose(file);
    }

 str = txt;
    ind_repre(str);
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        if (code[i]) printf("'%c': %s\n", i, code[i]);

    compress(str, buff);
    printf("compressedData: %s\n", buff);

    decompress(buff, q[1]);
    printf("decoding done ! check output file\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! It's debugger time!

Comment: This is either far from complete, or has some serious uninitialized variable use issues.  To start off with, you set `out` equal to `buf`, but `buf` has never been set to anything.

Comment: It's likely your trying to access something not properly allocated. In which case you need to provide more of your code.

Comment: I suspect `s[len]` is out of bound. C is 0 index language.

Comment: Debug tips: 1. compile with `-g` to include debug symbols.  2. run newly compiled version in `gdb`.  3. upon segfault, it will show you where that happened.  4. run with `valgrind --tool=memcheck`, which will tell you many things about your memory misuse issues.

Comment: @Sharat The usual approach here is to run your code until it explodes, then observe where the problem appears to be. Set a breakpoint a few steps before that and single-step towards where you're expecting it to blow up, carefully observing variables and return values. When it does blow up you should have a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: @JamesK since `buf` was not defined locally, it is global, therefore it was initialised.

Answer (score 3):

The debugger message shows, that indeed the call to `strcpy()` is the culprit:

> __strcpy_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S:57

Judging from the code you share, the buffer `buf` to which `out` points does not seem to be large enough to hold a string of length `len`, which you try to copy into it. Alternatively it could be possible, that `buf` is not in a writable part of your process memory.

In any case, make sure that `out` points to a writable buffer, which is large enough, perhaps by allocating some space to it, for example with:

```
static char *out = NULL;

if (out == NULL)
    out = malloc(len);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: That "solves" the issue at the expense of creating a memory leak. Far from ideal.

Comment: *** Error in `./huf': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x000000000229c030 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @Sharat hm, interesting... there is no free() in your code... It could be "hidden" in a call to fclose(), however. There seems to be another heap corruption somewhere, it is really hard to say without actual input and debugger. You could try to start your program with `valgrind`, which should easily show you invalid memory accesses

Comment: Actual input could be any string. Concept of this program is to read some data from txt file then Encode it using Huffman coding technique. Then Decode the Encoded value to get the original message.